# Not able to extract data into Pandas dataframe in correct format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, curl

I am trying to extract data from API and write into a Pandas Dataframe so that I can do some transformations .

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Api-Key',
}

params = (
    ('locodes', 'PLWRO,DEHAM'),
)

response = requests.get('https://api.xxx.com/weather/v1/forecasts', headers=headers, params=params)
```

## The result of the API Call

```
response.text

'{"results":[{"place":{"type":"locode","value":"PLWRO"},"measures":[{"ts":1571896800000,"t2m":10.72,"t_min":10.53,"t_max":11.99,"wspd":8,"dir":"SE","wgust":12,"rh2m":87,"prsmsl":1012,"skcover":"clear","precip":0.0,"snowd":0,"thunderstorm":"N","fog":"H"}]},{"place":{"type":"locode","value":"DEHAM"},"measures":[{"ts":1571896800000,"t2m":10.79,"t_min":10.3,"t_max":10.9,"wspd":13,"dir":"ESE","wgust":31,"rh2m":97,"prsmsl":1008,"skcover":"partly_cloudy","precip":0.0,"snowd":0,"thunderstorm":"N","fog":"H"}]}]}'
```

When Try to into pandas dataframe its not coming in the correct format.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
urlData = response.content
rawData = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(urlData.decode('utf-8')))
```

Current Output
[image]

How can I have values populating correctly under each header.

Expected format
[image]

Comment: Please can you show us what the output is? You've said it's not in the correct format but not showed us what output you're currently getting.

Comment: @elembie, I have updated the question with current Output  I am recieveing.

Comment: That's quite a nested json structure - inside each `result` you have a `place` which has `type` and `value`, as well as `measures` which seems to be a list of a single object with the measures as keys. What kind of tabular output are you expecting from this (e.g. what should each row look like)?

Comment: @elembie, I updated the question with a sample output format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert json to dictionaries, then is necessary some processing for add `locode` to `measures`, merge dictionaries, append them to list and last call `DataFrame` constructor:

```
import json

d = json.loads(response.text)

out = []
for x in d['results']:
    t = x['place']['type']
    v = x['place']['value']
    for y in x['measures']:
        y = {**{t:v}, **y}
        out.append(y)
#print (out)

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print (df)
  locode             ts    t2m  t_min  t_max  wspd  dir  wgust  rh2m  prsmsl  \
0  PLWRO  1571896800000  10.72  10.53  11.99     8   SE     12    87    1012   
1  DEHAM  1571896800000  10.79  10.30  10.90    13  ESE     31    97    1008   

         skcover  precip  snowd thunderstorm fog  
0          clear     0.0      0            N   H  
1  partly_cloudy     0.0      0            N   H
```

Answer (score 0):

you can process use [module Abstract Syntax Tree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=ast) (import ast) to convert string to Python dictionary. You can read more about a user-case of ast at this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

In your case I would do:

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

response = '{"results":[{"place":{"type":"locode","value":"PLWRO"},"measures":[{"ts":1571896800000,"t2m":10.72,"t_min":10.53,"t_max":11.99,"wspd":8,"dir":"SE","wgust":12,"rh2m":87,"prsmsl":1012,"skcover":"clear","precip":0.0,"snowd":0,"thunderstorm":"N","fog":"H"}]},{"place":{"type":"locode","value":"DEHAM"},"measures":[{"ts":1571896800000,"t2m":10.79,"t_min":10.3,"t_max":10.9,"wspd":13,"dir":"ESE","wgust":31,"rh2m":97,"prsmsl":1008,"skcover":"partly_cloudy","precip":0.0,"snowd":0,"thunderstorm":"N","fog":"H"}]}]}'

# convert response to python dict
response_to_dict = ast.literal_eval(response)

# convert response_to_dict into pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(response_to_dict['results'][0]['measures'])
```

Output:

```
|---|---|------|------|----|---|-----|------------|----|-----|----|
|dir|fog|precip|prsmsl|rh2m|...|t_min|thunderstorm|ts  |wgust|wspd|
|SE |H  |0.0   |1012  | 87 |...|10.53|N           |15..|12   | 8  |
|---|---|------|------|----|---|-----|------------|----|-----|----|
```

Comment: I am getting an error called `malformed node or string: <Response [200]>`

Comment: it does work for me, both on python 2.7 and 3. There is live code at this Google Colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qdUlSnOI4zDDDgof8DLGquR-rQMk42XH